# json-schema get the schema for given property in js

Tags: javascript, jsonschema

I was wondering wich could be a good approach to retrieve the schema for a given property of a schema.
if the given property name is present in schema's `properties` and it's declared or `$ref`erenced that's quite straightforward,
things get complicate when `anyOf` `allOf` `oneOf` or `dependencies` come into play..
i was wondering if there's a way to *hook* into a validation library in some way (tv4 or z-schema) to retrieve something like a `getPossibleSchemaForProperty(propname)` .
any suggestion for browser javascript?

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I am the lead maintainer for tv4*

Are you looking to get all possible schemas for that property, or only the ones that apply to a specific data instance (e.g. only the `oneOf` clause that matches)?  Assuming it's the latter (which I generally refer to as *"schema assignment"*):

There is an [open issue on tv4](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4/issues/140) for this, but I haven't heard any interest from other people until now, so I didn't prioritise it.  If people want it, I can add it.

[This other package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/json-model) (also mine, faster but fewer features) returns a map from JSON Pointers to schema URLs:

```
// Creates a validator for that schema
var validator = JsonModel.validator('https://example.com/schema1');

// Runs the validator on the data
var result = validator({
    "foo": {
        "bar": [1, 2, 3]
    }
});
// pass or fail
console.log(result.valid);
// list of schemas describing that sub-sub-property
var subSubSchemas = result.schemas['/foo/bar']);
```

Comment: hi @cloudfeet, at first glance `json-model` seems to be a great tool.. it wraps models making them schema-reactive... and the `Schema assignment` is very handy, despite i was asking for *all possible schemas for that property* thing.. i opened a [discussion](https://github.com/geraintluff/json-model/issues/1) on github to get deeply into this lib

Comment: i realized that the *schema assignment* is very handy too.. in my usecase most schemas do not allow multiple possible schema for one property. i'm trying to integrate `tv4` (or maybe `json-schema`) in angularjs directives, so i wish the controller to lookup for the schema of the property, knowing the property path..